# ft-models.out makefile error

Tags: linux, makefile, ubuntu-12.04

i just try to compile a makefile, But it didnt work,
My Makefile is this,

this is very important for me, i will upload and post a link for all folders,
if anyone can help me, probably he will go heaven :D
THIS IS LINK FOR MY ALL FOLDERS,
CAN ANYONE RUN THIS CODE ON LINUX??
http://s2.dosya.tc/server/OfLhtU/Desktop.zip.html

```
TRAIN=correctparses_03.txt.gz
TEST=test.1.2.dis.gz
FST=tfeatures.fst turknum.fst turkunk.fst unknown.fst
SCRIPTS=lookup dlist script.txt singleline.pl merge.pl features.pl ft-models.pl          ft-model-eval.pl
LIBS    =   -L"/usr/include/glib-2.0"   -lglib

all: eval.out

eval.out: test.features.gz ft-model-eval.pl ft-models.out
@echo === Evaluating the disambiguation model
zcat $< | ft-model-eval.pl -v > $@ 2> eval.err
tail -5 eval.err

test.features.gz: test.merge.gz features.pl
@echo === Preparing testing features for a +-2 word window
zcat $< | features.pl | gzip > $@

test.merge.gz: ${TEST} test.lookup.gz merge.pl
@echo === Merging answers in testing file with lookup results
merge.pl 'zcat ${TEST} |' 'zcat test.lookup.gz |'  2> $@.err | gzip > $@

test.lookup.gz: ${TEST} ${FST} script.txt singleline.pl lookup
@echo === Running lookup on the testing file
zcat $< | awk '{print $$1}' | lookup -f script.txt | singleline.pl | gzip > $@

ft-models.out: ft-models.pl dlist train.features.gz
@echo === Training individual feature models
ft-models.pl 'zcat train.features.gz |'

train.features.gz: train.merge.gz features.pl
@echo === Preparing training features for a +-2 word window
zcat $< | features.pl | gzip > $@

train.merge.gz: ${TRAIN} train.lookup.gz merge.pl
@echo === Merging answers in training file with lookup results
merge.pl 'zcat ${TRAIN} |' 'zcat train.lookup.gz |' 2> $@.err | gzip > $@

train.lookup.gz: ${TRAIN} ${FST} script.txt singleline.pl lookup
@echo === Running lookup on the training file
zcat $< | awk '{print $$1}' | lookup -f script.txt | singleline.pl | gzip > $@

clean:
-rm train.lookup.gz
-rm train.merge.gz train.merge.gz.err
-rm train.features.gz
-rm -rf ft-models.out
-rm test.lookup.gz
-rm test.merge.gz tst.merge.gz.err
-rm test.features.gz
-rm dlist.{dbg,tst,trn,val}
-rm eval.{out,err}


# To compile the dlist decision list induction program:

# CC=gcc
# CFLAGS=-O3 -Wall -I. `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`
# LIBS=`pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`

# dlist: dlist.o glib-ext.o
#   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@

# dlist.o: dlist.c glib-ext.h

# glib-ext.o: glib-ext.c glib-ext.h
```

when i run this make file the error is;

```
  make: ft-models.pl: Command not found
 make: *** [ft-models.out] Error 127
```

how can i fix it?? thanks...

,

FIRST ERROR ACTUALLY THIS

```
=== Running lookup on the testing file
zcat test.1.2.dis.gz | awk '{print $1}' | lookup -f script.txt | singleline.pl | gzip > test.lookup.gz
/bin/sh: 1: lookup: not found
/bin/sh: 1: singleline.pl: not found
=== Merging answers in testing file with lookup results
merge.pl 'zcat test.1.2.dis.gz |' 'zcat test.lookup.gz |'  2> test.merge.gz.err | gzip      > test.merge.gz
=== Preparing testing features for a +-2 word window
zcat test.merge.gz | features.pl | gzip > test.features.gz
/bin/sh: 1: features.pl: not found
=== Running lookup on the training file
zcat correctparses_03.txt.gz | awk '{print $1}' | lookup -f script.txt | singleline.pl | gzip > train.lookup.gz
/bin/sh: 1: singleline.pl: not found
/bin/sh: 1: lookup: not found
=== Merging answers in training file with lookup results
merge.pl 'zcat correctparses_03.txt.gz |' 'zcat train.lookup.gz |' 2> train.merge.gz.err | gzip > train.merge.gz
=== Preparing training features for a +-2 word window
zcat train.merge.gz | features.pl | gzip > train.features.gz
/bin/sh: 1: features.pl: not found
=== Training individual feature models
./ft-models.pl 'zcat train.features.gz |'
Finding unique morphological features in data
Found 0 morphological features
=== Evaluating the disambiguation model
zcat test.features.gz | ft-model-eval.pl -v > eval.out 2> eval.err
make: *** [eval.out] Error 127
```

Comment: This is the first error later on it gives an error like that which i wrote uper

Answer (score 0):

It may take several steps to solve this. On line 28, change this:

```
ft-models.pl ...
```

to this:

```
./ft-models.pl ...
```

Tell us the result (in a comment on this Answer).

**EDIT:**

Good! Now on lines 20 and 36, change this:

```
merge.pl ...
```

to this:

```
./merge.pl ...
```

And tell us what happens.

Comment: something changed... !
=== Training individual feature models
./ft-models.pl 'zcat train.features.gz |'
Finding unique morphological features in data
Found 0 morphological features
=== Evaluating the disambiguation model
zcat test.features.gz | ft-model-eval.pl -v > eval.out 2> eval.err
make: *** [eval.out] Error 127

Comment: /bin/sh: 1: merge.pl: not found